# This poem is titled Ζ-Gap

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, poetry, music, number-property

**The answer is a two-digit number.**

> Do whatever you want to play
> Solution is one step away
> Mine for alien harmony
>
> Take some notes you want to declare
> Regions you were so unaware
> Fundamental is always there
>
> Lurking frequencies over it
> Tiny steps between for the fit
> Radiating sounds are so lit

Comment: I can't explain the title. Any hints?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number is

> 19

Each line of the poem

> corresponds to an odd member of the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(music)). The first couple letters of the line represent the [solfege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge) of that pitch. Some of the harmonics are kind of weird or "alien".

*Do whatever you want to play*

> The first harmonic is the fundamental represented by **Do**.

*Solution is one step away*

> The third harmonic is the fifth scale degree or **Sol**.

*Mine for alien harmony*

> The fifth harmonic is the third scale degree or **Mi**.

*Take some notes you want to declare*

> The seventh harmonic is a weird flat seventh scale degree. A major seventh would be *ti*, a flat seventh can be represented by *te* or **Ta**.

*Regions you were so unaware*

> The ninth harmonic is the second scale degree or **Re**.

*Fundamental is always there*

> The eleventh harmonic is a weird sharp fourth scale degree. A perfect fourth would be *fa* so a messed up one could be **Fu**.

*Lurking frequencies over it*

> The thirteenth harmonic is another weird one. It's close to a flat sixth scale degree. A regular sixth is *la* so a weird one could be **Lu**.

*Tiny steps between for the fit*

> The fifteenth harmonic is a relatively accurate leading tone or **Ti**.

*Radiating sounds are so lit*

> The seventeenth harmonic is a flat second scale degree or **Ra**.

So what next?

> *The solution is one step away. Mine for alien harmony.*
> The next odd harmonic is the **nineteenth** harmonic which is a sharp second or flat third scale degree.